# Утечка памяти java

Tags: java, android, memory

Добрый день!
Подскажите пожалуйста почему происходит бесконечная утечка памяти при таких действиях.
В методе OnCreate создаю объекты.

`WorkshopDamage = new ConstraintLayout(this);`

`backWorkshopDamage = new ImageView(this);`

При нажатии кнопки выполняется этот метод.

```
 public void WorkshopDamage(){
    //WorkshkopDamage Layout
    WorkshopDamage.setId(R.id.WorkshopDamage);
    WorkshopDamage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_help);
    gameScreen.addView(WorkshopDamage);
    params.constrainHeight(R.id.WorkshopDamage, ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT);
    params.constrainWidth(R.id.WorkshopDamage, ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT);
    params.connect(R.id.WorkshopDamage, ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.TOP);
    params.connect(R.id.WorkshopDamage, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
    params.connect(R.id.WorkshopDamage, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
    params.connect(R.id.WorkshopDamage, ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.LEFT);
    params.applyTo(gameScreen);
    //backWorkshopDamage
    backWorkshopDamage.setId(R.id.backWorkshopDamage);
    backWorkshopDamage.setImageResource(R.drawable.backgame);
    WorkshopDamage.addView(backWorkshopDamage);
    params.constrainHeight(R.id.backWorkshopDamage, ScreenHeight/15);
    params.constrainWidth(R.id.backWorkshopDamage, ScreenHeight/15);
    params.connect(R.id.backWorkshopDamage, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.WorkshopDamage, ConstraintSet.TOP);
    params.connect(R.id.backWorkshopDamage, ConstraintSet.LEFT, R.id.WorkshopDamage, ConstraintSet.LEFT);
    params.applyTo(WorkshopDamage);
    backWorkshopDamage.setOnClickListener(GameClick);
}
```

Затем я делаю.

```
      case R.id.backWorkshopDamage:
                WorkshopDamage.removeAllViews();
                gameScreen.removeView(WorkshopDamage);
                break;
```

При старте приложения потребляется 10 мб, после зацикливания этих действий стабильно выдаёт 10.40 -10.90мб куда делить 900кб если я удаляю делаю remove?

Comment: Нашёл где происходит утечка. Сделал дампы памяти, в итоге создается бесконечно Integer и HashMap@HasMapEntry. Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Ну, как минимум, посмотреть, где у вас в коде используются HashMap и Integer, я полагаю